# Add fields to the form using ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms, dom

I'm trying to add fields to a form, apparently with you, but when I send your form to the fields added with ajax are not sent. I think the fields that were added were not recorded in the DOM

**Javascript**

```
$(function(){
    if($('[data-fornecedor-produtos]').length > 0){
        role = $('select').data('fornecedor-produtos');
        $('[data-fornecedor-produtos]').on('change', function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            $.ajax({
                url: 'index.php?r=logistica%2Flogisticatransferenciassolicitacao%2Fproducts',
                data: {e:1,data:$(this).val()},
                method: 'GET',
                complete: function(retorno){
                    $('[role="'+role+'"]').html(retorno.responseText);
                }
            });
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: in theory this should work. do fields that come from ajax have "name" attributes? is "$('[role="'+role+'"]')" located inside "<form>" ?

Comment: yes ,already checked all

Comment: How do you send that generated form? Could you post code?